# how to enable intel iris xe gpu support for comfyui

Tags: python

I'm working on an ai image creating project and im using ComfyUI_windows_portable_nvidia_cu121_or_cpu. And it only uses either nvidia or cpu. But i don't have a nvidia gpu. And making a good quality image using cpu takes forever. Does anyone know if there is a way to enable intel iris xe gpu support for comfyui

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the Irix Xe an integrated GPU? I don't think you'd get much of it even it was supported. I'm pretty sure it's not supported, so, unfortunately `--cpu` is your only option.

Otherwise I think in order to make it work on GPU, your GPU should be either:

- Supported Nvidia GPU
- Supported Radeon GPU see supported GPUs of ROCm
- Supported Intel Arc (probably) see https://github.com/comfyanonymous/ComfyUI/discussions/476

Support also differs depending from the OS, something supported on Windows might not necessarily have support on Linux.

I'd recommend you to update your question with more details:

- What is your OS (we can try to deduce that you're on windows, bit it's better to specify explicitly)
- What is your GPU exact model
- Which ML models are you trying to use

Comment: It is better to ask for clarification _prior_ to posting an answer. Given you do not have enough rep to comment yet, the appropriate action is to flag this question as "Needs details or clarity" or "A community-specific reason > Needs debugging details".